# How to change color inside radio form

Tags: html, css

I have the below form that is composed of two radio buttons.
I can get the type to have the color that I want via the CSS, but the below male and female values remain in white and the CSS is not changing their color.

```
<div class="form-title-radiobuttons">Type</div>
<input class="form-title-radiobuttons" type="radio" name="type" value="male"  checked> Male<br>
<input class="form-title-radiobuttons" type="radio" name="type" value="female"> Female<br><br />
```

```css
.form-title-radiobuttons {
  margin-bottom:10px;
  color: #725129;
  text-shadow: #fdf2e4 0 1px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are closing the `</div>` already, before including the `input` and text. The scope of the colour is only for the `Type`. Also adding the `<label>` tags would give you a lot of clickable area to the radio buttons. This should work:

```css
.form-title-radiobuttons {
  margin-bottom:10px;
  color: #725129;
  text-shadow: #fdf2e4 0 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-title-radiobuttons">Type<br>
  <label><input class="form-title-radiobuttons" type="radio" name="type" value="male"  checked> Male</label><br>
  <label><input class="form-title-radiobuttons" type="radio" name="type" value="female"> Female</label><br><br />
</div>
```

Comment: I should add, the most appropriate way to do this is with a `<label></label>` tag.

Comment: @FaustoNA Added `label`. Check?

Comment: I would go `<input id="myInput"><label for="myInput">Label</label>` that has the same effect and is more compliant with standards (I think?).

Comment: @FaustoNA That's a big debate happening always. Think about `input`s that do not have `id` or have dynamically generated `id`, so in those cases, it is effective to have everything encapsulated inside a single `<label>`... :)